# Modifying how text is copied from a web page where whitespace has been rendered visible

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, parsing, clipboard

I've been working on creating an HTML parser and formatter, and I've just added a feature to optionally render whitespace visible, by replacing spaces with `·` (middle dot) characters, adding arrows for tabs and newlines, etc.

[image: screenshot of HTML formatting]

The full in-progress source code is here: https://github.com/kshetline/html-parser, and the most relevant file that's doing the CSS styling of HTML is here: https://github.com/kshetline/html-parser/blob/master/src/stylizer.ts.

While it's nice to be able to visualize whitespace when you want to, you wouldn't want spaces to be turned into middle dot characters if you select and copy the text. But that's just what happens, at least without some intervention.

I have found a crude way to fix the problem with a bit of JavaScript, which I've put into a Code Pen here: https://codepen.io/kshetline/pen/NWKYZJg.

```
document.body.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
  let selection = document.getSelection().toString();

  selection = selection.replace(/·|↵\n|↵/g, ch => ch === '·' ? ' ' : '\n');

  event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', selection);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

I'm wondering, however, if there's a better way to do this.

My first choice would be something that didn't rely on JavaScript at all, like if there's some way via CSS or perhaps some accessibility-related HTML attribute that would essentially say, "this is the real text that should be copied, not what you see on the screen".

My second choice would be if someone can point me to more detailed documentation of the JavaScript clipboard feature than I've been able to find, because if I have to rely on JavaScript, I'd at least like my JavaScript to be smarter. The quick-and-dirty solution turns *every* middle dot character into a space, even if it was truly supposed to be a middle dot in the first place.

Is there enough info in the clipboard object to figure out which of the selected text has what CSS styling, so I could know to convert only the text that's inside `<span>`s which have my `whitespace` class, and still also find the rest of the non-whitespace text, in proper order, to piece it all back together again?

Comment: Since you're already adding styling, it seems like you could just take that a step further by wrapping each space in a span, and add an `:after` to those spans whose `content` is set to middle dot (and additional CSS to get it to overlay the space). CSS `content` content doesn't copy but the space will copy.

Comment: That does sound like it would work, but wow, that could be a lot of extra markup, since currently I combine runs of whitespace into a single span. Still, it doesn't require any JavaScript, and that's a great plus. I did just work out the JavaScript, however! :)

Answer (score 1):

I still couldn't find much documentation on how selection objects work, but I played around with them in the web console, and eventually figured out enough to get by.

This is the JavaScript I came up with:

```
function restoreWhitespaceStrict(s) {
  return s.replace(/·|[\u2400-\u241F]|\S/g, ch => ch === '·' ? ' ' :
           ch.charCodeAt(0) >= 0x2400 ? String.fromCharCode(ch.charCodeAt(0) - 0x2400) : '');
}

const wsReplacements = {
  '·': ' ',
  '→\t': '\t',
  '↵\n': '\n',
  '␍\r': '\r',
  '␍↵\r\n': '\r\n'
}

function restoreWhitespace(s) {
  return s.replace(/·|→\t|↵\n|␍\r|␍↵\r\n|→|↵|␍|[\u2400-\u241F]/g, ws =>
    wsReplacements[ws] || (ws.charCodeAt(0) >= 0x2400 ? String.fromCharCode(ws.charCodeAt(0) - 0x2400) : ''));
}

document.body.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
  const selection = document.getSelection();
  let newSelection;
  let copied = false;

  if (selection.anchorNode && selection.getRangeAt) {
    try {
      const nodes = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents().childNodes;
      let parts = [];

      // nodes isn't a "real" array - no forEach!
      for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
        const node = nodes[i];

        if (node.classList && node.classList.contains('whitespace'))
          parts.push(restoreWhitespaceStrict(node.innerText));
        else if (node.localName === 'span')
          parts.push(node.innerText);
        else
          parts.push(node.nodeValue);
      }

      newSelection = parts.join('');
      copied = true;
    }
    catch (err) {}
  }

  if (!copied)
    newSelection = restoreWhitespace(selection.toString());

  event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', newSelection);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

I've tried this on three browsers (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari), and it's working on all of them, but I still took the precaution of both testing for the presence of some of the expected object properties, and then also using try/catch, just in case I hit an incompatible browser, in which case the not-so-smart version of fixing the clipboard takes over.

It looks like the selection is handled as a list of regular DOM nodes. Chrome's selection object has both an `anchorNode` and an `extentNode` to mark the start and end of the selection, but Firefox only has the `anchorNode` (I didn't check Safari for `extentNode`). I couldn't find any way to get the full list of nodes directly, however. I could only get the full list using the `cloneContents()` method. The first and last nodes obtained this way are altered from the original start and end nodes by being limited to the portion of the text content that was selected in each node.